# Slicing a pandas data frame using a specific hours

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame that includes a datetime column in the next format: 1/11/2019 20:59.
The data frame contains dates from the last month and I'd like to slice it into 2 new dataframe:

1. all raws that are between 02:10-09:00
2. all raws that are between 09:00-02:10

Answer (score 1):

You can set your datetime column to a DateTimeIndex then execute the `pandas.between_time` function.

```
df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['datetime']), inplace=True)
slice1 = df.between_time('02:10','09:00')
slice2 = df.between_time('09:00','02:10')
```